# How to find specific element in a matrix dependent on row and column conditions

Tags: r, matrix

I have a very large matrix (around 30,000,000 columns) which has numerous columns with the same name. I am trying to find the row and column number of an entry which satisfies certain row and column conditions. For example, the first few entries of my matrix are as follows:

```
             Day 1     Day 1     Day 1     Day 1     Day 1     Day 2     Day 2     Day 2     Day 2     Day 2
[1,]         1         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0
[2,]         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
[3,]         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

What I would like, is to have a command, or create a function which tells me the row and column number of the entry which has column name equal to `Weekday 'x'`, (for any `x`) and row y value equal to `1`, for any `'y'`.

There will only be one answer to each combination I enter, but I cannot get my code to work.

For example, I know that entry `[1,1]` has value `1`, so I have written:

```
   > w1 <- which(colnames(year)=="Day 1")
   > wd1 <- (year[1,w1]==1)
   > which(wd1==T)

    Day 1 
        1
```

This output is not specific and does not include column number. The column name doesn't help as there are many columns with the same name.

Comment: What's the goal of all this at end ? I've the feeling `df[,colnames(df) == "Day2"] == 1` would return a usable logical matrix for what's coming up next...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like, given a row number `y` and a day `d` you are seeking all the column numbers in the original matrix for which:

1. The value in row `y` is set to 1
2. The column name indicates the column is for day `d`

This is a 1-liner in R:

```
get.cols <- function(y, d) unname(which(year[y,] == 1 & colnames(year) == paste("Day", d)))
get.cols(1, 1)
# [1] 1
get.cols(2, 1)
# integer(0)
get.cols(1, 2)
# [1] 7
```

If you instead wanted to find all row/column pairings where the matrix was set to 1 and the column name matches the indicated day, you could:

1. Subset the matrix to the columns for the specified day
2. Use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` to find all row/column pairs in the subset that are set to 1
3. Map the column numbers back to the original matrix's column numbers

You could do that with something like:

```
get.rowcol <- function(day) {
  w <- which(colnames(year)==paste("Day", day))
  matches <- which(year[,w] == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
  matches[,"col"] <- w[matches[,"col"]]  # Map column numbers from subset to full matrix
  matches
}
get.rowcol(1)
#      row col
# [1,]   1   1
get.rowcol(2)
#      row col
# [1,]   1   7
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to get index information, then you can use the arr.ind argument to the which() function.

```
#for any entry = 1
which(year == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

or

```
#for your example of a specific column name and entry value
which(colnames(year) == "Day1" & year == 1, arr.ind=TRUE) 

Working example:
year <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), .Dim = c(3L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Day1", "Day1", 
"Day1", "Day1", "Day1", "Day2", "Day2", "Day2", "Day2", "Day2"
)))
which(colnames(year) == "Day1" & year==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
indx <- function(colNAME, num=1) {
  cols <- which(colnames(year) == colNAME)
  x <- which(year[,cols] == num)
  clmn <- cols[ceiling(x/nrow(year))]
  rw <- x %% nrow(year)
  matrix(c(rw,clmn),ncol=2)
}

indx("Day1")
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
```

In the output, the first column is the row the second is the column.

**Data**

```
year <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), .Dim = c(3L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Day1", "Day1", 
"Day1", "Day1", "Day1", "Day2", "Day2", "Day2", "Day2", "Day2"
)))
```